# Failed to setup loop device while mounting .iso file

Tags: mount, iso, matlab

I am trying to install Matlab R2013A in Ubuntu 15.04 using an .iso file and:

- I logged in as super user using sudo su.
- I made a directory for a mount point using "mkdir -p /mnt/disk"
- To mount the `.iso` I used: `mount -o loop Matlab_801_R2013a_MacUnix /mnt/disk`

but got the following error:

```
mount: Matlab_801_R2013a_MacUnix: failed to setup loop device: No such file or directory
```

*Could someone please explain me what is a loop setup and how I can solve this problem?*

Comment: What is the exact iso file name and location ? You may need to add `.iso` at the end of the file name and include the exact path if the iso is not in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

You need the complete path for your iso file:

```
mount -o loop <path_to_iso>/Matlab_801_R2013a_MacUnix.iso /mnt/disk
```

And `.iso` files usually have an extension. Check that and note the correct spelling of the file..